# How to add multiple values to a multi value drop down field in Rally using python and pyral

Tags: python, rest, rally, pyral

I'm trying to update a multi value drop down list field (custom field) in Rally using python2.7 and pyral (v 1.3.2).

I can add a single value to the field like this:

```
>>> update_data = {'FormattedID' : 'US58848', 'c_MapProfile' : {'ObjectID' : 129751972040}}
>>> rally.post('UserStory', update_data)
<pyral.entity.HierarchicalRequirement object at 0x6fffea46c50>
```

This updates the field to the attribute value specified by the ObjectID. 
The object ID in the MapProfile dict points to the AllowedAttributeValue object.

However, I don't seem to be able to figure out, how to add multiple values to the field.

Can anybody give a hint? Or does pyral not support multi-value fields?

Thanks
Thomas

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the pyral toolkit, but I can say the api expects the data in a certain shape.

```
'c_MapProfile':[
  {'_ref':'/allowedattributevalue/123'},
  {'_ref':'/allowedattributevalue/124'}]
```

I believe you can retrieve the allowed values for your custom field using the [getAllowedValues](http://pythonhosted.org/pyral/interface.html#getAllowedValues) function

Keep in mind this will overwrite any existing values. If you only wish to add or remove entries without overwriting the current value - use the collection endpoints as explained in the [CA Agile Central Web Services API Documentation](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/)